# Воспроизвести видео со страницы на телевизоре

Tags: html5, google-chrome, видео, samsung

Речь об этом:

[image: скриншот угла плеера ютьюба] [image: скриншот запроса]

Компьютер и телевизор находятся в одной сети (компьютер подключен к роутеру кабелем, телевизор - через wifi). Никаких дополнительных устройств (например, miracast-адаптеров) нет. Если при работающем телевизоре запустить видео на YouTube, то внизу появляется кнопка, позволяющая воспроизвести видео на телевизоре:

[image: скриншот окна браузера]

1. Как это устроено?
2. Могу ли я взять тег `video` на любом сайте и через какое-то api из devtools инициировать запрос на воспроизведение на телевизоре (ну и начать воспроизведение после подтверждения)?
3. Могу ли я на своём сайте сделать кнопку, которая будет просить воспроизвести некое видео (не с YouTube) на телевизоре? Эта ситуация отличается от предыдущей, потому что на своём сайте я могу размещать дополнительные service worker'ы в случае, если они для этого понадобятся.

```css
html, body, video { height: 100%; margin: auto; display: block; }
```

```html
<video controls>
  <source src="//www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="//www.w3schools.com/html/movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/cast ? вроде то https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference

Comment: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cast-videos-chrome#0

Comment: @МихаилКамахин, вроде вот их пример https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-chrome, но запустить пока не получилось.